# Populate a textbox based on selected value from dropdown using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox, dropdown

I tried to search posts, without any result either, maybe I didn't use the right words.

I am using `ASP.NET MVC` to create a webpage with a form.

The form has a `dropdownlist` and a `textbox`.

The `dropdownlist` is populated with values from the database.

The `textbox` will populate with a value from the same table and the `dropdownlist`, based on the selected `dropdownlist` value.

My goal is to call a function from my `controller` inside of my view, is that possible?

My code below

**Models**

```
namespace InsGE.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> Fruits { get; set; } //DropDownList

        public string Names { get; set; } //Textbox
        
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace InGE.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static List<SelectListItem> PopulateFruits()
        {
            string sql;

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                sql = @String.Format("SELECT * FROM `dotable`; ");

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            items.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = sdr["sName"].ToString(),
                                Value = sdr["sCode"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return items;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
        {    
            string sNames = person.Names;

            PersonModel fruit = new PersonModel();
            fruit.Fruits = PopulateFruits();

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fruits, Model.Fruits, "Please select")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the text box when selecting an item in the dropdown by using javascript.

The following code should help you in the right direction. Place the code at the bottom of your view.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>

        document.getElementById('ddlFruits').addEventListener('change', function() {
            var textBox = document.getElementById('textBoxId');
            textBox.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        });
        
    </script>
{
```

We add a `addEventListener` to the dropdown when the page loads with a function that runs everytime the user selects a fruit in the dropdown. When the user selects a fruit the  `function` in the `'change'` event fires and updates the textbox with the selected text from the dropedown.

### Update based on comments

Add the following controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetGps(string fruit)
{
    PersonModel fruit = new PersonModel();
    var gps = fruit.GetGps(fruit);
    return gps;
}
```

You will need jQuery for this to work: https://jquery.com/download/

Add the following jQuery code in your script tag:

```
$("#ddlFruits").change(function () {

    var fruit = this.text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetGps',
        type: "GET",
        data: { fruit },
        success: function (gps) {
            $("#textBox").val(gps);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. I have tried your suggestion, but the texbox is populated from selected value on dropdownlist. I need execute the query for extract the value for populated the textbox. E.g. : Select Paris value on DDL and the query extract GPS value and populate textbox... maybe my question is not well explained

Comment: Alright, so when the user selects an item in the dropdown, it should query the database with the selected value and return GPS values and then populate the textbox with the values?

Comment: That can be done with an `ajax` call. I will update my answer.